# Dynamic javascript C# Google Chart

Tags: c#, javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to display a google chart with dynamic data when my page loads.  For clarification I'm using webMatrix (asp.net, c#, sql db).

I have c# codebehind which is querying my main database every 5 minutes and storing the data in a server database "Target".

My goal is to use "Target" as the datasource for the google chart. I'm really confused by the google chart documentation because all of the examples are showing javascript code with hardcoded data.  How can I manipulate the javascript so that it contains my dynamic data?

```
      <script>
        function initialize() {
          var db = 'Target'
          var query = new google.visualization.Query(db);

          query.setQuery('select Problem group by Queue');

          query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {

          if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
          }

          var data = response.getDataTable();
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
          chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true});
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this one out...

I didn't realize that razor syntax allows codebehind variables within a script.

C#

```
{
int a = 100;
int b = 350;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    dataArray = [];



    dataArray[0] = ['0', 'Title1', 'Title2'];
    dataArray[1] = ['Element 1', @a, 0];
    dataArray[2] = ['Element 2', 0, @b];

    function drawChart() {


        //var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        //dt.addRows(data);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

        var options = {
            title: 'Tickets',
            vAxis: { titleTextStyle: { color: 'red'} },
            backgroundColor:  'lightgray'

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What about dynamic ?? The elements from a list ?